# How to find a region of acceptability in sympy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math, algebra

Firstly, sorry about machine translate of "region of acceptability", I'm not sure that is exactly what I mean. "region of acceptability" must tell me where `f(x)` exists.

I'm using `sumpy` to code a script which will be give me a full `f(x)` analysis:
`f(x)=0`, `d/dxf(x)=0`,"region of acceptability", etc.

Which function in `sympy` is what I'm searching and how to use it correctly?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find the domain of the function excluding any singularities?

Comment: yes, i suppose that what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in sympy called `singularities` that tries to identify the set of singularities for an expression in a given symbol:

```
In [21]: from sympy import *                                                                                                                   

In [22]: x = Symbol('x', complex=True)                                                                                                                       

In [23]: expr = x**2 / ((1 - x) * (2 + x**2))                                                                                                  

In [24]: expr                                                                                                                                  
Out[24]: 
        2       
       x        
────────────────
        ⎛ 2    ⎞
(1 - x)⋅⎝x  + 2⎠

In [25]: singularities(expr, x)                                                                                                                
Out[25]: {1, -√2⋅ⅈ, √2⋅ⅈ}
```

If the broader domain of the function is supposed to be the reals then you can remove those singularities from the set of real numbers using set subtraction:

```
In [26]: Reals - singularities(expr, x)                                                                                                        
Out[26]: (-∞, 1) ∪ (1, ∞)
```

You can also convert that into relations on `x` with:

```
In [27]: (Reals - singularities(expr, x)).as_relational(x)                                                                                     
Out[27]: x ≠ 1
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed, and sorry that I don`t confirmed your answer so long.